# How to make this row-wise operation performant (python)?

Tags: python, pandas

My issue is very simple, but I just can't wrap my head around it:
I have two dataframes:

1. time series `dataframe` with two columns: `Timestamp` and `DataValue`
2. A time interval `dataframe` with `start`, `end` timestamps and a label

What I want to do:

Add a third column to the timeseries that `yields` the labels according to the time interval `dataframe`.

Every `timepoint` needs to have an assigned label designated by the time interval `dataframe`.

This code works:

```
TimeSeries_labelled = TimeSeries.copy(deep=True)
TimeSeries_labelled["State"] = 0
for index in Timeintervals_States.index:
    for entry in TimeSeries_labelled.index:
         if Timeintervals_States.loc[index,"start"] <= TimeSeries_labelled.loc[entry, "Timestamp"] <=     Timeintervals_States.loc[index,"end"]:
             TimeSeries_labelled.loc[entry, "State"] = Timeintervals_States.loc[index,"state"]
```

But it is really slow. I tried to make it shorter and faster with pyhton built in filter codes, but failed miserably.
Please help!

Comment: Hi! For Pandas questions, best include some your actual data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/463796

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know about TimeSeries, with a dataframe containing timestamps as datetime object you could use something like the following :

```
import pandas as pd
#Create the thrid column in the target dataframe
df_timeseries['label'] = pd.Series('',index=df_timeseries.index)
#Loop over the dataframe containing start and end timestamps
for index,row in df_start_end.iterrows():
    #Create a boolean mask to filter data
    mask = (df_timeseries['timestamp'] > row['start']) & (df_timeseries['timestamp'] < row['end']) 
    df_timeseries.loc[mask,'label'] = row['label']
```

This will make the rows your timeseries dataframe that match the condition of the mask have the label of the row, for each rows of your dataframe containing start & end timestamps

Comment: Wow! This does the same job, but incredibly fast. Thank you so much, this was exaclty what I needed!!